# How can i add right join to other table in this code

Tags: join

I have this code runninh:

```
SELECT IDLOTE,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO='2020-01-01'
                THEN cargo
                ELSE 0
                END) *4 as saldo,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO>'2019-12-31' and (idconcepto=2 or idconcepto=4 or idconcepto=22 or idconcepto=23 or idconcepto=24)
                THEN cargo
                ELSE 0
                END) as saldo2,
       SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO<='2019-12-31'  
                THEN cargo-abono
                ELSE 0
                END) as saldo3,
        SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO<'2020-01-01' 
                THEN cargo-abono
                ELSE 0
                END) as saldo4,
        SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO>='2020-01-01' and (idconcepto=2 or idconcepto=4 or idconcepto=22 or idconcepto=23)
                THEN cargo
                ELSE 0
                END) as saldo5    
FROM polizamovtos 
GROUP BY IDLOTE
HAVING SUM(cargo) > SUM(abono)
```

So, i need to add right join on idlote with the table propietarios

I try with this code:

```
SELECT IDLOTE,
   SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO='2020-01-01'
            THEN cargo
            ELSE 0
            END) *4 as saldo,
   SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO>'2019-12-31' and (idconcepto=2 or idconcepto=4 or idconcepto=22 or idconcepto=23 or idconcepto=24)
            THEN cargo
            ELSE 0
            END) as saldo2,
   SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO<='2019-12-31'  
            THEN cargo-abono
            ELSE 0
            END) as saldo3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO<'2020-01-01' 
            THEN cargo-abono
            ELSE 0
            END) as saldo4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO>='2020-01-01' and (idconcepto=2 or idconcepto=4 or idconcepto=22 or idconcepto=23)
            THEN cargo
            ELSE 0
            END) as saldo5    
FROM polizamovtos t1
INNER JOIN asignarlotes on asignarlotes.IDLOTE=polizamovtos.idlote
GROUP BY IDLOTE
HAVING SUM(cargo) > SUM(abono)
```

Comment: which rdms are you using and what is the problem when you simply inner join your table

Comment: WHEN I TRIED, I RECEIVED THIS ERROR #1052 - La columna: 'IDLOTE' en field list es ambigua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the second table, mysql doesn't know which column to choose, when they have the same name like IDIOTE, so choose one.

I changed the alias for polizamovtos  to `p` and give `a` to asignarlotes, that makes it easier to read and you know always which table you want to use

```
SELECT p.IDLOTE,
   SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO='2020-01-01'
            THEN cargo
            ELSE 0
            END) *4 as saldo,
   SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO>'2019-12-31' and (idconcepto=2 or idconcepto=4 or idconcepto=22 or idconcepto=23 or idconcepto=24)
            THEN cargo
            ELSE 0
            END) as saldo2,
   SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO<='2019-12-31'  
            THEN cargo-abono
            ELSE 0
            END) as saldo3,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO<'2020-01-01' 
            THEN cargo-abono
            ELSE 0
            END) as saldo4,
    SUM(CASE WHEN FECHAMOVTO>='2020-01-01' and (idconcepto=2 or idconcepto=4 or idconcepto=22 or idconcepto=23)
            THEN cargo
            ELSE 0
            END) as saldo5    
FROM polizamovtos p
INNER JOIN asignarlotes a on a.IDLOTE=p.idlote
GROUP BY p.IDLOTE
HAVING SUM(cargo) > SUM(abono)
```

Comment: it works but i cant see the columns of asignarlotes. The result only shows same columns

Comment: i actually don't know your tables or what you want to show, but now you can add every column from a to your select, it will showm the value of the join  table. to get a better view. make SELECT p.*,a.* FROM.... and then you see what every ro looks like. If my answer help you,. please [accept it](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: Thanks man, it works